# size of grids in each and every row and column of main grid is getting reduced

Tags: c#, wpf

I have declared a grid in xaml-

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="RejectedPartsGrid" >
 </Grid>
```

This grid is populated with small grids from code behind-

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
            RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();

            RejectedPartsGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);

            RejectedPartsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
        }

            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {

                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                {

                    Grid gridImages = new Grid();

                    gridImages.Background = Brushes.Pink;

                    Grid.SetColumn(gridImages, column);

                    Grid.SetRow(gridImages, row);




                    gridImages.Margin = new Thickness(10);

                    ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();

                    Image image = new Image();
                    image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

                    if (imageCount < ListRejectedCarPartNames.Count)
                    {

                        carPartName = ListRejectedCarPartNames.ElementAt(imageCount);
                        conn.Open();
                        if (carPartName.Trim() != String.Empty)
                        {
                            using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT CarImage FROM CarPartsImageMapping where CarPart = '" + carPartName + "'", conn))
                            {

                                SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {

                                    carImagePath = reader.GetString(0);

                                }

                            }
                            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + carImagePath, UriKind.Relative));
                            myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
                            gridImages.Background = myBrush;
                        }

                        conn.Close();
                    }

                    RejectedPartsGrid.Children.Add(gridImages);

                    imageCount++;
```

}

I am using kinect,when i swipe left image in the small grids loads,but the problem is initially when the window loads,the size of the small grids inside main grid is big enough,but after the swipe action when the image loads in the small grids the size of the grid reduces,on second swipe it reduces more.. – I want the gridImages grid to be static all the time,how to do this?

Comment: There is something missing in the code you posted, please edit

Comment: I am using kinect,when i swipe left image in the small grids loads,but the problem is initially when the window loads,the size of the small grids inside main grid is big enough,but after the swipe action when the image loads in the small grids the size of the grid reduces,on second swipe it reduces more..

Comment: You can set the grid width and height according to your size

Comment: i have already tried this,but still the saize of small grids inside main grid is getting shrinked

Comment: As you said i already tried by adding this code- gridImages.Height = 100;gridImages.Width = 100;,but still it shrinks